# round a date in R to an arbitrary minute/hour level of precision

Tags: r, datetime, rounding

I'm looking to group dates in R by an arbitrary level of precision.

It's pretty straightforward to do this to the nearest hour or minute, using e.g. `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
nearest_hour = floor_date(now(), 'hour')
```

You can then group a list of such dates with e.g. a simple `summarise` `ddply` from `plyr`.

What I'd like to do is round dates with arbitrary precision, e.g. to the nearest 15 minutes or every 3 hours:

```
nearest_three_hours = floor_date(now(), '3 hours')
```

There's a discussion of such things at http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Truncating-dates-and-other-date-time-manipulations-td866901.html but outside of cutting dates, there doesn't appear to have been any resolution.

Comment: If you have a vector of times to subset from, then you could use the `endpoints` function in [xts](http://cran.project.org/package=xts): `library(xts);x <- .POSIXct(0)+1:10*60*60; x[endpoints(x, "hours", 3)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lubridate already floors to the nearest atomic unit. To get floor to the nearest 15 minutes, which I think is what you want to do (not round), you just need to map into the correct range via findInterval and a defined set of breakpoints. Try this floor_time, which is functionally equivalent to floor_date, but allows you to specify a variable # of units for seconds, minutes or hours.

```
floor_time <- function(x, k = 1, unit = c("second", "minute", "hour", "day", 
                                          "week", "month", "year")) {
  require(lubridate)

  nmax <- NULL

  switch(unit, second = {nmax <- 60},
         minute = {nmax <- 60},
         hour = {nmax <- 24})

  cuts <- seq(from = 0, to = nmax - 1, by = k)
  new <- switch(unit, 
                second = update(x, seconds = cuts[findInterval(second(x), cuts)]), 
                minute = update(x, minutes = cuts[findInterval(minute(x), cuts)], 
                                seconds = 0), 
                hour = update(x, hours = cuts[findInterval(hour(x), cuts)], 
                              minutes = 0, seconds = 0), 
                day = update(x, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0), 
                week = update(x, wdays = 1, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0), 
                month = update(x, mdays = 1, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0), 
                year = update(x, ydays = 1, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0))

  new
}
```

Comment: lubridate now has this functionality in it's round_date function, please use that instead

Answer (score 9):

A little late, and I don't have rep to comment, but as Selva mentioned, lubridate now has this functionality:

```
library(lubridate)
round_date(now(), '3 hours')
floor_date(now(), '3 hours')
ceiling_date(now(), '3 hours')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, still based on the `lubridate` library

```
library(lubridate)
round_minute<-function(x,precision){
  m<-minute(x)+second(x)/60
  m.r<- round(m/precision)*precision
  minute(x)<-m.r
  second(x)<-0
  x
}

round_minute(ymd_hms(c("2013-06-03 22:53:00","2013-05-03 12:18:00","2013-05-03 00:10:00")),15)

> "2013-06-03 23:00:00 UTC" "2013-05-03 12:15:00 UTC" "2013-05-03 00:15:00 UTC"
```

The code handle well all the tricky situations thanks to `lubridate`. Of course this function works only for precision expressed in minutes but you can easily extend it to other units, and even create a generic function if you really need it.

Answer (score 5):

`lubridate` now has a more generic `round_date()` function.

```
lubridate::round_date(date, "5 mins")
lubridate::round_date(date, "2 hours")
```